# Hangfire Recurring job not running in a timely manner on IIS

Tags: iis, jobs, hangfire, recurring

I have a web service on IIS that does the following:

1. I have 2 recurring jobs that internally creates around 800 jobs. The recurring job is supposed to run at midnight.
2. Hangrire is using MSSQL in the background.

I expected the recurring jobs to run at midnight.
But when I logged into the hangfire dashboard the next day, the recurring jobs got kicked off then (and not at midnight).

I was wondering whether this issue was beacuse my request to the hangfire request after the app pool refresh attributed to this behavior.

Comment: Don't use any scheduling framework on IIS. Don't even think about it, as it goes against IIS design (idle shutdown/application pool recycle and so on). Write a Windows service app, or use Windows scheduler directly.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [this](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html)?

As it says on the Hangfire docs:

> By default, Hangfire Server instance in a web application will not be
>   started until the first user hits your site. Even more, there are some
>   events that will bring your web application down after some time (I’m
>   talking about Idle Timeout and different app pool recycling events).
>   In these cases your recurring tasks and delayed jobs will not be
>   enqueued, and enqueued jobs will not be processed.

Also, don't forget to run `iisreset` after you're done, since the new configs need to be loaded up by the IIS server.

Comment: For additional info see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59718263/4180382