# Hangfire jobs not running on my Asp .Net Core-site

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

**To sum up the text below: What do I have to do to run Hangfire jobs when there are no users on my web page?**

Im running asp net core and have started using Hangfire for recurring tasks on my web application. I left it running on my job for the weekend but when I get back no jobs has been run. After googling a bit I've got that it seems to be a "fix"/method for this [on hangfires docs](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html), but it seems to be made for non-core. Do I need a special handling for this in .Net Core (with app.UseHangFireServer() and so on?

Comment: I have the same problem for over a month now and have had to log into the server every week. Simply viewing the dashboard gets things going again and I can't figure out why this is happening. Are you running it on IIS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) ... It got resolved, but I think in my case, it might be that I used an illegal Cron-expression. To me honest I dont really remember :/ ...an after everything worked(in IIS) I moved it ru turun ina console app anyway...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that hangfire will only wake up after a refresh of your website by pressing F5 in the browser.

I was having the same issue for our .NET core webservice that I fixed as follows.

- Our IIS version : **7.5**
- Our Server : **Windows Server 2008 R2**

1) You will need the so called Application Initializer which you can download here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization
Download and run the MSI. Once installed, you will probably have to reboot the server.

2) Open applicationHost.config which is at **%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\config** in Notepad, being sure to run it with the “Run as Administrator” option. **Do not use Notepad++** see: https://serverfault.com/a/599865.

3) Find the  configuration section, and then look for the application pool running your gallery. If you don’t know the pool name, look it up in IIS Manager by right-clicking the application node in the left pane and choosing Manage Application > Advanced Settings. Add **startMode=”AlwaysRunning”**  so that it looks like this:

```
<add name="OGF.Home.Webapi" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion=""  startMode="AlwaysRunning" >
```

4) Scroll down a little more in applicationHost.config to the  configuration element. Find the entry for the gallery application and add **preloadEnabled="true"** , like this:

```
   <site name="OGF.Home.Webapi" id="10" serverAutoStart="true">
   <application path="/" applicationPool="OGF.Home.Webapi" preloadEnabled="true">
   ...
```

5) Restart IIS by executing iisreset in a command prompt running as an administrator.

For Windows Server 2012 and higher you can configure these settings directly in IIS by opening the "Advanced Settings" menu for the application pool and the website after installing the Application Initializer.

Comment: I would add that the application pool should be set to NET CLR Version v4.0.30319 instead of No managed code for .net core apps. This was my problem. It's about halfway down the page of the hangfire documentation in section "Making ASP.NET Core application always running on IIS" https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html